# How to convert string to datetime format classic asp

Tags: asp-classic

I have one variable

```
Dim tt="2008-10-20 10:00:00.0000000"
```

I want to change it into date,

Answer (score 5):

Try `CDATE(tt)` see http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_cdate.asp. I used

> vbscript cdate

as keywords at Google. There were more results.

Edit: Based on the comment below (I'm sorry for mixing up), using

```
FormatDateTime(date,format)
```

Format contains following constants:

- 0 = vbGeneralDate - Default. Returns date: mm/dd/yy and time if
  specified: hh:mm:ss PM/AM.
- 1 = vbLongDate - Returns date: weekday,    monthname, year
- 2 =    vbShortDate - Returns date: mm/dd/yy
- 3 =    vbLongTime -    Returns    time: hh:mm:ss PM/AM
- 4 =    vbShortTime - Return    time:    hh:mm

(copied from http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_formatdatetime.asp)

Comment: Thanks for your replay, but i want to change it into datetime not only date.

Comment: Note: link appears to be dead (and it is generally held the w3schools links are often less valuable than others)

Comment: @JohnHascall Look at the date. and look at the last comment in post

Comment: In my opinion this doesn't address the problem. The request is to convert string to date using a specific format for the date.

Answer (score 2):

This link, ([MS CDate page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dt118h2%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)), explains that:

```
adate = CDate(astring)
```

converts a string into a date object.  For there, you can format it with the [FormatDateTime function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8aebkz6s%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)

```
str = FormatDateTime(Date)
```

the `FormatDateTime` function is "smart" -- it will format as date and time if both are present, otherwise it will format with whichever of date or time is present.

Answer (score 2):

I propose a safe solution which returns the result only if the conversion is successful:

```
s="2008-10-20 10:00:00.0000000"
On Error Resume Next
d=CDate(Left(s,19))
On Error Goto 0
if not IsEmpty(d) then MsgBox d
```

Try it for a non-valid date or non-valid format. The result will be empty.

```
s="2008-02-31 10:00:00"
```

In same contexts, it is necessary to initialize the variable collecting result of CData. I recommend to initialize it as Empty. Example below shows such case - counting valid dates in a string array:

```
Lines = array("2008-10-20 10:00:00.0000000", "2008-10-20 10:00:00", "", "2008-02-31", "Today", "2017-02-7")
On Error Resume Next
Count=0
for each Line in Lines
    d=Empty
    d=CDate(Line)
    if not IsEmpty(d) then Count=Count+1
next
On Error Goto 0
MsgBox "Number of valid dates is "&Count
```

The correct answer is 2. Without initialization we get 5 as the CDate does not do anything on error so variable keeps the value from a recent iteration in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

If do not need your milliseconds, your could use the following:

```
<script type="text/vbscript">
    s="2008-10-20 10:00:00.0000000"
    arr= Split(s, ".")
    d=CDate(arr(0))
    document.write(d)
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe cdate is dependent on local settings to parse the string. This is no good in many situations.

To avoid this you need to use 
DateSerial()

and if needed add any time components to the result separately.

Comment: True. See my answer for a sample using Dateserial()

Answer (score 0):

The date literal in classic asp is unreliable. If the first or second part is greater than 12, it takes that value for day, the other as month. If both parts are less than 12, the interpretation is unpredictable: sometimes american and sometimes british.

A work-around is to force the entry of dates into separate fields or use a date entry module which can set the date into british or american style.

A date literal should be treated as american and use a function to convert that into a date variable using Dateserial().

```
function amerdate(str)
  'str 3/5/2023 form: in american format: use for calculations including date
  Dim d 
  d = Split(str, "/")
  amerdate = Dateserial(d(2), d(0), d(1))
end function
```

Use only american date in calculations like Dateadd() etc.

```
someday = "3/5/2023" '5th march, american date literal
nextday = Dateadd("d", 1, amerdate(someday))
```

Whenever a date display is required, convert to british date and show it.

```
function britdate(str)
  'str: 3/5/2023 form: display in british form. not for calculations
  Dim d 
  d= Split(str, "/")
  britdate = d(1) & "/" & d(0) & "/" & d(2)
end function
```